# Why isn't null included in PySpark filter's "!=" condition?

Tags: pyspark, filter, conditional-statements

In this example dataset/code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "All canines"),
        (2, None),
        (3, "Test"),
    ],
    ["row_id", "animal"]
)

df = df.filter(df.animal != "All canines")

return df
```

I would expect it to return row id 2 AND 3 but for some reason it's only returning row id 3. I mean I could easily do which works:

> df = df.filter((df.animal != "All canines") | (df.animal.isNull()))

But I don't get PySpark's logic in also stripping away the null in the condition statement. What's happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE operators filter rows based on the user specified condition. A condition expression is a boolean expression and can return `True`, `False` or `Unknown (NULL)`. They are “satisfied” only if the result of the condition is **True**.

Comment: So you're saying that "abc" == null for example evaluates to unknown (null) instead of false? I mean logically speaking it should be false...

Comment: ```"abc" == null``` evaluates to unknown (null)  sure. Apache spark supports the standard comparison operators such as ‘>’, ‘>=’, ‘=’, ‘<’ and ‘<=’. The result of these operators is unknown or NULL when one of the operands or both the operands are unknown or NULL. In order to compare the NULL values for equality, Spark provides a null-safe equal operator (‘<=>’), which returns False when one of the operand is NULL and returns ‘True when both the operands are NULL.

Comment: That was extremely helpful, I did not know about this. Thank you.